# Why would my server's SSH key regenerated on an apt-get upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, ssh

I manage a few servers at DigitalOcean and have been upgrading computers many times and never had a problem.

Today, I did the usual upgrade sequence:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The upgrade worked just fine. I did not notice anything specific. The files that were installed are:

```
apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libfreetype6  librtmp1
```

After my 3 computers where upgraded, I ran a restart with:

```
sudo init 6
```

Once rebooted, I tried to connect with SSH and I got an error telling me that the computer may have been hacked:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:lkAyAr1g1aym6K3tNV0jEYSLejJcGmK/7tEBgApVbck.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/alexis/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/alexis/.ssh/known_hosts:100
remove with:
ssh-keygen -f "/home/alexis/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 45.55.5.185
ECDSA host key for 45.55.5.185 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Looking at the `/etc/ssh` folder, I noticed that all the keys where updated as of the time I upgraded the computer...

Why would that happen?

Comment: Why would the key change on an upgrade? It seems that the title is the question here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually talked with someone at DigitalOcean and they explained that when an upgrade happens, the node may be bounced from one supervisor to another.

In order for their nodes to function, they need access to the running node and they use those keys. Each supervisor will make use of different keys. So just a jump will force the regeneration of new keys.

So the fact that the key changed is benign as far as we are concerned, although it is problematic when you have automatic processes that count on those keys to never change.